# float value after second position in time 04:55:49.9242 ( what is this .9242)

Tags: python, datetime, time

Can anyone please explain me "2018-04-17 04:55:49.9242" what is the .9242 after :sec value.

i am parsing some data from json. one of the file contains this value. i know the date format how is here. only have some doubt in .9242 part.

Comment: It is fractions of a second, in your case it is 9242/10000 of a second.

Comment: Are all timestamps in your data formatted like this? Typically, you'd have milli- or microseconds, but not hundreds of microseconds (3 or 6 digits of fractional seconds).